# Difference between "composite" and "compound"

Tags: differences, nouns, adjectives

Is there any difference between *composite* and *compound*? Are these words synonyms?

Comment: In chemistry, they are not synonyms. Can you give a little more context or the sentences in which you're wanting to use them?

Comment: I'm not thinking on chemistry context. It is more a computer science context, for example an operation that consists of other simpler operations, is a composite operation or a compound operation? I'm not sure which one sounds better and why...

Comment: @CarlosLoth, Like in this article? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key (It says compound and composite keys are different.)

Comment: This article compares composites, compounds and alloys, with great definitions and illustrations: https://msestudent.com/the-difference-between-alloys-and-composites-and-compounds/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Composite* are engineered materials made from two or more constituent materials with significantly different physical or chemical properties and which remain separate and distinct on a macroscopic level within the finished structure.

A *compound* is a substance consisting of two or more different elements chemically bonded together in a fixed proportion by mass and it is a substance that can be split up into simpler substances.

Yes, they are synonyms.

Comment: Could do with some sources here. I'm sure definitions with subtle differences could also be found.

Answer (score 6):

It is a debatable subject. I have had many ***composite*** and ***compound*** crossbows and bows.

Composite is something that is made from two or more materials usually for extra strength, flexibility or durability, e.g. when they put a plaster cast on a broken limb it is made from plaster (or a similar substance) and bandage. The bandage alone is not strong enough on its own to hold the bone it place to heal and the plaster is to brittle to last the amount of time it would take for the bone to heal itself (it would simply crack and break), but fused with the fibre's of the bandage it becomes much stronger. It is ***macroscopic*** because you can see the fibres in the plaster with the naked eye as opposed to ***microscopic*** which is something that cannot be seen with the naked eye.

Something that is ***compound*** is made from two or more materials that is bonded at the ***molecular*** level, e.g. one of my bows is made from ***carbon*** and ***aluminium*** but to the naked eye it looks like it is made out of a ***single*** material because they are bonded at a ***microscopic*** level.

English is a debatable language, the ***meaning***, ***spelling*** and use of ***grammar*** and ***Punctuation*** of many words is still hotly debated, e.g. ***Non debatable*** (I now, ironic isn't it!), ***Nondebatable*** and ***Non-debatable***

As long as you are consistent throughout your work, e.g. if you used ***23*** in a sentence and then later used ***forty-one it would be wrong, you *must* put ***41*** or Change the ***23*** to ***twenty-three***.

Material sourced from: myself.

Answer (score 1):

The usual usage in IT is “*compound* statement”. You won’t be prosecuted for using *composite*. In IT *compounding* operations and variables “build up” the statement. *Composite* doesn’t cover that meaning.

Comment: What would you say if it was not an operation, but a structure, like "composite app", or page? (I know "compound document" is a thing, but also feel "composite" to be kinda natural in this context.)

Answer (score -1):

The difference is, compound can be a verb. Composite can only be a noun or an adjective.

Comment: Several dictionaries report verb senses of _composite_ (meaning “to make a composite”).